# What is the correct usage of "was"

Tags: passive-voice, past-simple, active-voice

> I was requested that documents yesterday.
>   I requested that documents yesterday.

Which one is correct the one, with was or without was?

Answer (score 3):

They mean something completely different. As user57399 noted, in both cases you should use *those*, or use the singular *document*.

If you say

> I was requested that document yesterday.

You mean that *someone else* asked you for the document. You did not request it, someone else requested it, from you. However, the sentence is not natural, because we need, as @BobRodes points out in his comment, an infinitive after requested in this case.

So if you were asked for the document, you could say:

> I was requested *to provide* the document yesterday.

If you say

> I requested that document yesterday.

You were the one that asked for the document.

So both sentences can be correct, but it depends on what you mean to say.

Comment: I can't see any circumstance under which the first sentence is correct. If you substitute *I was asked the documents yesterday* it should be clear that *I was asked for the documents yesterday* is correct. But I have to think about exactly why.

Comment: Ok, I've thought about it. *Request* and *ask* are similar in their usage, and the circumstances in which the verb functions with or without a preposition are idiomatic. In this particular case, the verb takes the form of *ask somebody to do something*. Therefore, an infinitive must be provided: *I was requested to provide that document yesterday*, for example.

Comment: @BobRodes You are right, of course. Something didn't feel right about that passive version. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: How about. "**I was requested for that document yesterday.**"?

Comment: @SovereignSun When you are *requested for* something, it means that you are asked to fulfill a specific purpose, typically by being selected from a group. *I was requested for work on that document* would mean that someone asked to have me, specifically, work on the document, as opposed to others who could have been selected. *Selected* is a more typical verb: *I was selected for special guard duty*, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Without "was". The word "requested" is itself the past form of the verb request. By the way, your sentences are incorrect in another way, because if using the plural "documents" you must say "those" not "that".

So: "I requested those documents yesterday" (plural)
Or: "I requested that document yesterday" (singular)

Comment: What if I request the documents from you? Then you were requested the documents...

Comment: @oerkelens Again, *you were requested to send the documents*, or some such.